# make gameObject visible and have correct color in gameplay, and make object have appropriate speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity2D,
So I'm creating a game in 2D where AI agent and enemies walks around a floor with doors to spawn the enemies and alcoves to hold the items that the agents has to collect. I created circles to represent the enemies and applied a material with red color on it.  But in the game play, the color is black as you can see in the following picture:

Also, the two of the grey walls are missing as well in the game play. The floor has z-position = 0 and the obstacles has z position -2.

[image]

Furthermore, I used `transform.Translate(new Vector3(movingSpeed,0,0) * Time.deltaTime);` in the fixedUpdate method to move the object, but in the game play it went off super fast. However, the movingSpeed is only set to 0.01.

[image]

Comment: Check the location of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

> I created circles to represent the enemies and applied a material with red color on it. But in the game play, the color is black as you can see in the following picture

You should add a light component or change your shader of material.

> transform.Translate(new Vector3(movingSpeed,0,0) * Time.deltaTime);

You should use [Rigidbody2D.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) funciton.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `Rigidbody` **never** change the position through the `Transform` component but rather use [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html). This keeps the Physics and collisions etc intact.

That it kind of flies off right at the beginning suggests there might be an issue with colliders probably?

The colors seem to be a lightning problem. The disappearing objects might be related to the positioning of your Camera and the near clipping plane but both is hard to tell without more details.